# I can't send a message to another user from Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: python, botframework

It is impossible to send a message to another user from the bot in Microsoft Teams. It constantly sends messages to me although all the parameters are passed from the database.

Anton: name of db table

```py
async def create_reply_activity2(text) -> Activity:
    return Activity(
        type=ActivityTypes.message,
        channel_id=Anton.query.all()[0],
        conversation=Anton.query.all()[1],
        recipient=Anton.query.all()[3],
        from_property=Anton.query.all()[2],
        text=text,
        service_url=Anton.query.all()[4])

resp = await create_reply_activity2("yo.")
    await context.send_activity(resp)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? Are you saying you want to respond to a message from one user by sending a message to a different user? Has that other user already contacted the bot, or would this message be starting a new conversation?

Comment: yes, second user already connected to bot, in db his info like from_property, etc

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is send a [proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message). Ordinarily, bots function by only sending a message to a user when that user sends a message to the bot in what's called a turn. Since you want to send a message to a user outside of a turn in response to something other than that user messaging the bot, the message is considered proactive. Therefore, you shouldn't be trying to send a message using the turn context because that context applies to the turn that's between the bot and the user who messaged it.

Instead of sending a message like this:

```
await context.send_activity(resp)
```

You should be sending a message like this:

```
credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
connector = ConnectorClient(credentials, base_url=context.activity.service_url)
connector.conversations.send_to_conversation(Anton.query.all()[1].id, resp)
```

Of course, you should be storing the result of the query so you don't have to be running the same query over and over again.